# Windows Azure - portability and migration?

Tags: azure

We are looking to use Windows Azure to host our existing SaaS platform and extend our functionality and capability. WE will be taking adavantage of both the data storage and application and web service functionality of Azure.

My question is as follows:
Some of our clients will not want Public CLoud access. Since our datastore stores sensitive client data many of them will require our whole system to be hosted internally on their own network and servers.
If we setup a full Azure setup of database and connected applications and processes how difficult is it to be able to duplicate that system for a specific client on their own servers and network using existing Microsoft technologies?

I know its a vague question and I also have a liminted understanding of Azure so whatever information you can provide here would be most appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5084013/333404

Comment: thank you that didnt solve the problem but definitely gave me more information

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need the flexibility of a hybrid cloud/on-prem solution. Likely the best solution is the [Windows Azure Service Bus](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/service-bus/). Essentially, you configure a WCF web service in the cloud (SOAP, REST, etc) that performs asynchronous brokered messaging between your on-premise application and your web application. This can be performed using queue messages, for example:

1. The web application (cloud) requests resources from the brokering service (cloud) by sending a queue message
2. The service handles the queue message and makes it available to the consuming (on-prem) service
3. On-prem service checks for new messages from the brokering service, gets the request for data, and returns desired data from DB
4. On-prem service sends message to brokering service with desired data
5. Web app (cloud) checks for new messages from the brokering service, then uses the data from on-prem service

Service bus is secure, asynchronous, fault-tolerant, and ensures that both components are decoupled.

Another method is to use [Windows Azure Connect](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/virtual-network/), which is a VPN solution that sets up network-level connnectivity. I recommend Service Bus because it promotes a more robust and scalable architecture, and fault-tolerance is high.

Comment: thanks for your ideas...I will look further into Service Bus and Connect. My issue however is not to MIX on-premise and cloud but rather have the ability to create an on-premise instance of my cloud service for particular clients. I want to know that I can do that with minumum hassle or integration. Basically a cloud solution that can easily be reproduced on-premise. Oracle have this functionality and I was hoping to find it in Microsoft too.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the clarification. Running a cloud solution on-premise only makes sense if you're trying to take advantage of the benefits of Azure in the first place -- namely scalability and availability, among other benefits. If you're looking for a "private cloud" that has these benefits, you might want to check [this out](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/community/partners/windows-azure-appliance/). It basically duplicates the Azure environment, but on-premise. Otherwise, you might just want to run standard Microsoft stack technologies locally and use Azure only as needed.